# PNY ExpressCard SATA II 2-port card - drivers?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I bought a couple of PNY eSATA cards for notebook computers, model P-NSA2-EC-RF.

I mistakenly thought that they would be a bit more plug-and-play, like cards that supply USB or Firewire ports.

They did not ship with the Driver CD, and the drivers I found on the PNY web site didn't work.  I've emailed their support group, but we all know how likely it is that they will respond before the end of the decade.

Does anyone have a driver disc handy for this model card, or know where I might download a driver ISO?

(Dell XPS M1330 laptop running Windows 7 x64 and sometimes Windows 7 x86)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find nothing on the PNY web site, and the Silicon Image drivers that match the controller on this ExpressCard did not match the hardware, according to Windows.

I finally found a set of drivers that works for this particular card, both 32- and 64-bit.  I've installed and tested the 32-bit drivers in Windows 7, and they work great.

http://driverscollection.com/?file_cid=393614976152d20ca47aed24724

I usually steer clear of these generic driver sites, but this solution worked fine, and no pop-ups or membership fee.

Thanks to others who lent a hand.

-- Brian

Answer (score 1):

I belive it has a Silicone Image chipset and if you can find the driver for this, some have reported it working-SiI3132 - PCI Express (1x) to 2 Port SATA300

Hope that helps.PNY sure does not make it easy!

Comment: I've tried Silicon Image drivers as well, but they haven't worked.  I suppose my laptop could have a bad card slot.  I'll see if I can test the card on another machine.  (My other laptops have CardBus, not ExpressCard, so I may have to try one from work.)

Comment: Does the card appear in device manager?

Comment: Startech has several eSATA cards that use the Silicon Image chip set. Worth looking at. http://ca.startech.com/product-list/sata-cards